# Диагностика hdd в ноутбуке lenovo

Tags: железо, hdd

Недавно подвисла винда (курсор двигался, а задачи не отвечали), при перезапуске видел, как запустилась chkdisk. Потом при следующем перезапуске автоматически вошло в восстановление системы. Сейчас винда грузится, но примерно минут 10, появляется раб. стол, но работать невозможно.

В итоге решил проверить жесткий. Нашел в boot меню ноута пункт Lenovo diagnostic. Там запустил recover bad sector tool. В итоге имею следующее: 1.5 часа работает тест, из 1.5 млрд секторов проверено порядка 10 млн, При этом уже больше 1000 ошибок в секторах. (Очень смущает время выполнения, при такой скорости хватит на неделю и то, что ошибки идут фрагментами. Не одиночный сектор, а по 10, 20, 50, 100 штук подряд)

Собственно вопрос: стоит ли доверять стандартной проге и диагностировать смерть диска или же стоит попробовать сделать загрузочную флешку с прогой какой-то и погонять этот диск из под DOS? Или может быть попробовать что-то еще?

В сервисе, понятное дело, сразу скажут, мол платите, покупайте новый диск, Мы сами все сделаем и сами поставим. Но хочется убедиться, прежде чем тратиться.

Ноут Lenovo v580
диск Hitachi Hts541075a9e680 750Gb.

UPDATE: Попробовал MHDD, дополняю вопрос SMART-ом и результатами обычного `scan` на 23% примерно (Думаю там уже достаточно, чтоб поставить диагноз).Стоит ли смысл восстанавливать вообще этот HDD: Пробовать делать erase или remap... или может сразу в мусорку?

Первый тест родными средствами:

[image: скриншот]

Скрин SMART из MHDD:

[image: SMART]

Результаты простого `scan` на 23%:

[image: Результаты]

Comment: IBM продало свой бизнес жёстких дисков Hitachi. Именно после этого Hitachi диски "сыпались" просто косяками. Это так, урок истории. (У меня в своё время был винчестер IBM на полгигабайта)

Comment: http://hdd-remont.livejournal.com/

Comment: @0andriy, не поверишь, по нашей внутренней статистике хитачи - самые живучие винты на данный момент. А вот синие wd не любим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скрину - тебе все ответят "покупай новый винт". Кроме меня. Я отвечу: спасай свои важные файлы на другой винт\флэшку\облако и или покупай новый винт. Этот ещё можно вроерить `MHDD for DOS` выставив режим контроллера винта в `IDE`. Если биос конечно умеет. Живой терабайтный винт проверяется по повержности 3 часа. Плюс-минус 5 минут. Пятисотка соответственно часа за полтора.

Ещё было бы неплохо чтобы ты дополнил вопрос выхлопом S.M.A.R.T. Особенно интересует пункт "Rellocated sector count".

Comment: В смарт смотрел 3-6 месяцев назад, там живенько все было (какая-то из десктопных программ auslogics). Состояние диска отмечало, как хорошее. Попробую MHDD, Если там можно в смарт глянуть, то обновлю вопрос скрином смарт. П.с. тест крутился до сих пор, на 50 млн секторов вырубил, тест около 5000 ошибок насчитал. По времени где-то 6 часов. Прогресс 3%.

Comment: @Bogdan, mhdd ценен тем, что проверяет физические сектора на то живы они или нет и какое время отклика у каждого из них. Смарты тоже есть, но это не киллер-фича проги.

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил несколько скринов. Судя по скринам, стоит ли лечить диск? Данные сохранены, если что.

Comment: @Bogdan, даже при одном UNC его надо уже переводить в разряд "ну мы туда скинем фильмы, которые лежат в интернете и если винт умрёт - нам похрен". А у тебя - 2к таких. Просто выкинь или используй в качестве подставки под горячую сковородку с картохой. Для академического интереса - можешь запустить сканирование с режимом "Remap: ON". Но только для академического. НЕ продакшн.